# Do not print media from django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I created a custom widget and included a `Media` class.

```
class MyWidget(forms.MultiWidget):

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('path-to-css.css',),
        }
        js = (
            'path-to-js.js',
        )

    def __init__(self, visible_input_attrs=None, hidden_input_attrs=None):
        widgets = (
            TextInput(attrs=visible_input_attrs),
            HiddenInput(attrs=hidden_input_attrs),
        )
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(widgets)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return ['', value]
        return [None, None]
```

In my form I use this widget as follows

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = [
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'phone_number',

            ]
            widgets = {
                'phone_number': MyWidget(),
            }
```

My template file

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static i18n crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

      <form id="my-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Contact details</h2>
        {% crispy user_form %}
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock content %}

{% block javascript %}
  {{ block.super }}
  {{ user_form.media.js }}
{% endblock %}
```

In my template file I include the form with `{% crispy user_form %}` (using crispy forms). Django hereby automatically adds the CSS and JS files at the beginning of the form. Since I load JS files at the very end of every HTML page and since the included `path-to-js.js` file requires jQuery, I append `{{ user_form.media.js }}` to my javascript block in my template. As a consequence, `path-to-js.js` appears more than once on my page and leads to error messages because the first time `path-to-js.js` is loaded, jQuery is not loaded yet.

**How can I avoid to load the JS files when I use** `{% crispy user_form %}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `include_media = False` in your [helper](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html) class.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.include_media = False
```